# is possible to do case-insensitive search through _.includes?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am using underscore library to search element in array.

```
   var names=["Name1","Name2"]
   _.includes(names,'name1')
```

when i run this it showing false is there any way to search through case-insensitivity thorugh this or any other way?

Comment: _.include([1, 2, 'fida'].map(function(el){
  return typeof el==='string'?el.toLowerCase():el;
}), 'Fida'.toLowerCase());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [**some**](http://underscorejs.org/#some) instead:

```
_.some(["Name1","Name2"], function(el) { return el.toLowerCase() === 'name1'; });
```

```js
var result = _.some(["Name1","Name2"], function(el) { 
  return el.toLowerCase() === 'name1'; 
});
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use LodashJS library
[enter link description here](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#filter)

_.filter(users, { 'user': 'Barney'.toLowerCase() });

hope this helps...